# Is it possible to use Composition for polynomial composition?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I want to do this:

$P = (x^3+x)$

$Q = (x^2+1)$

$P \circ Q = P \circ (x^2+1) = (x^2+1)^3+(x^2+1) = x^6+3x^4+4x^2+2$

I used `Composition` for testing if that could be done then :

```
Composition[p, q][x^3 + x, x^2 + 1]
```

> ```
> p[ q[ x + x^3, 1 + x^2]]
> ```

I've also tried to use `Expand` on it but It didn't work. The nearest thing I could do was this:

```
a = x^2 + 1;  Expand[ a^3 + a]
```

> ```
> 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6
> ```

I was thinking that doing it by hand on longer compositions would be tedious, is there a function or way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work :

```
p[x_] = x^3 + x;
q[x_] = x^2 + 1;

Composition[p, q][x]

(* 1 + x^2 + (1 + x^2)^3 *)

Composition[Expand, p, q][x]

(* 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6 *)
```

Comment: If you don't want to define separate functions: `Composition[Function[x, x^3 + x], Function[x, x^2 + 1]][x] // Expand`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `p`, `q` had been defined this way :

```
p[x_] := x^3 + x 
q[x_] := x^2 + 1
```

then `Composition[p, q][x^3 + x, x^2 + 1]` couldn't have  worked because `q` had been defined as a function of one variable, this however would have worked :

```
Composition[p, q][x]
```

but to get what you intended (i.e. $g = p \circ q\;$)  you would rather use :

```
g[x_]:= Composition[ Expand, p, q][x]
g[x]
```

> ```
> 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6
> ```

Another way would be to use pure functions, e.g.

```
Clear[ p, q, g]
p = #^3 + # & ;
q = #^2 + 1 &;
```

now we can use it like this :

```
g = Composition[ Expand, p, q];
g[x]
```

> ```
> 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6
> ```

In such a simple case as you consider you can also get rid of `Composition` defining `g` like this (it doesn't matter if `p` and `q` are pure functions or not):

```
Clear[ g]
g[x_] := p[ q[x]] // Expand
g[x]
```

> ```
> 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6
> ```

`Composition` is especially useful when you have a list of functions, e.g.

```
lf = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10};
```

then apply it to this list :

```
(Composition @@ lf)[x]
```

> ```
> f1[f2[f3[f4[f5[f6[f7[f8[f9[f10[x]]]]]]]]]]
> ```

**Edit**

The original example in the question isn't especially interesting to demonstrate how `Composition` can be useful. Consider e.g. Laguerre polynomials, we define :

```
L[k_] := LaguerreL[k, #] &
```

e.g. :

```
L[5][x]
```

> ```
> 1/120 (120 - 600 x + 600 x^2 - 200 x^3 + 25 x^4 - x^5)
> ```

```
Plot[ L[#][x] & /@ Range[5], {x, 0, 3}, Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Now we can find compositions of subsequent Laguerre polynomials starting from `2`- nd to `n`- th, e.g. :

```
GraphicsGrid[
    Partition[
        Table[ Plot[ (Composition @@ (L[#] & /@ Range[k, 2, -1]))[x], {x, 0, 1.5},
                      PlotLabel -> Range[2, k], PlotStyle -> Thick],
               {k, 3, 6}], 2]]
```

[image]

We could get the same with other `Mathematica` functions like e.g. `Fold`, `FoldList` etc.
but `Composition` makes the task simpler and more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to employ rules

```
x /. x -> p  /. x -> q
```

> ```
> 1 + x^2 + (1 + x^2)^3
> ```

You can also `Expand` it

```
x /. x -> p  /. x -> q // Expand
```

> ```
> 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6
> ```

### **Edit**

Expanding on J. M.'s comment, this approach can be packaged in a function easily:

```
polyComposition[polyList_] := Fold[ReplaceAll, x, Thread[x -> polyList]] // Expand
polyComposition[{p, q}]
```

> ```
> 2 + 4 x^2 + 3 x^4 + x^6
> ```

Comment: Or, `Fold[ReplaceAll, x, {x -> x^3 + x, x -> x^2 + 1}]`.